# Adjust last row after inserting rows within a For Loop - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a large set of data that needs to be broken up based on group type in column 4. The goal of the loop is to insert three blank rows and copy-paste the sheet's header on top of the new group. This should continue until the bottom row row. However, it seems like my `lastrow3` isn't updating within the loop to account for the new rows inserted. Is there anything I'm missing in re-designating the last row within this For-Next Loop? Thanks!

```
    Dim lastrow3 As Integer, Dim b As Integer
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
    lastrow3 = ActiveCell.Row
  
    For b = 2 To lastrow3
        If Cells(b, 4) <> Cells(b + 1, 4) Then
        Rows(b + 1).Resize(3).EntireRow.Insert
        Rows("1").Copy
        Rows(b + 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        Rows(b + 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        lastrow3 = lastrow3 + 3
        b = b + 4
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I have not tested your code, however generally it is a bad idea to modify the counter variable inside of a for loop since it can cause weird bugs. You might want to try another loop like a while loop or do until loop (i don't remember exactly what they are called in vba)

Comment: @garbb you called it. I updated my answer to reflect your observation. Since you didn't post answer I went an upvoted your encrypt answer (which is interesting).

Comment: @muzikman, I updated my answer (my first one wasn't that great). If this works, I'd be grateful if you clicked the green accept check. Also, you do have an error in your posted code.  It should be `Dim lastrow3 As Integer, b As Integer` however, I'm guessing that isn't in your real code or it wouldn't run at all.

Comment: Key point here is that changing `lastrow3` inside the For loop has no effect on the loop target.  The For caches that value when the loop begins, changing the variable after that has no effect on the loop.  Side note, changing the loop counter does work, but is considered bad practice @PGSystemTester

Comment: @chrisneilsen sorry, not sure what you're saying in relation to me. Did I misstate something?

Comment: @PGSystemTester _Did I misstate something_ no, not at all. Just thought you might be interested in the details of how a For loop actually behaves

Comment: @chrisneilsen I'm always eager to learn, but I'm uncertain what you're telling me. When yous say, "changing the loop counter" -- Are you talking about the cached value? I'm not familiar with how to do that.

Comment: @PGSystemTester ok, I'll try to be more specific.  In the context of the OP's code, changing `b` inside the the loop _will_ affect the For loop.  Changing `lastrow3` will not.  The For loop terminates when `b` equals the value that `lastrow3` had when `For b = 2 To lastrow3` was executed,  no matter what you did to `lastrow3` in the mean time. It's a subtle point, but  one that makes your answer to use `Do While` instead the correct answer.

Comment: @PGSystemTester that worked! I wasn't aware that a row couldn't be updated within a For Loop. I will make sure to use Do-While loop in the future. I just need to update a bit of code to ensure the row header isn't copied a final time over non-existent data. Thanks all!

Comment: Also, do you mind explaining how the theEndRange row is updated to a new last row when rows are inserted? I thought the Range("A1").End(xlDown) is equivalent to a CTRL+Down shortcut and since it's out of the loop, it wouldn't update for inserted rows after the End(xlDown) is inserted before the loop. Apologies if this is a simple question. As have probably ascertained, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**. @garbb makes the right call in the comments. Your For loop is flawed in that you're setting it to end at a specific integer, however this number could change. Basically, you want the loop to continue until it reaches the cell that was was originally marked, taking into account the inserted rows. This can be accomplished by using a [Do-While loop](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-while-loop/) which evaluates the row number of that cell if it's set to a variable. As a variable, it will update as you insert rows which addresses your issue.

I tested this out and it should work. Make sure the `b=b+1` is in the proper spot. I can't tell without seeing what you did.

```
Dim theEndRange As Range
    Set theEndRange = Range("A1").End(xlDown)

Dim b As Long
    b = 2
    
    'set the looping rule here
    'theEndRange will update as rows are inserted.
Do While b <= theEndRange.Row
    
    If Cells(b, 4) <> Cells(b + 1, 4) Then
        Rows(b + 1).Resize(3).EntireRow.Insert
        Rows("1").Copy
        Rows(b + 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        Rows(b + 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        b = b + 4
    Else
        'without this your code will loop indefinitely!!
        'if this is causing an issue, it may need to place outside if statement
        b = b + 1
    
    End If
    'or here
    'b = b+1
Loop
```